# html embedded in jsp

Tags: html, jsp

i have an registration page in jsp in which html have been embedded...after the registration i want my page to be redirected to log in page for logging in but am unable to do that..kindly please help out how to do that..i have given href but its not working..this the code kindly help me out..

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Online pool</title>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function welcome(){
alert("Thanx for registering");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 5%">
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
<div id="wrapper" class="well">
<center>
<h1><font color="red"><i>New Passenger Registration</i></h2></font>
<form action="empadd.jsp" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Employee Id</label>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<input type="number" name="eid" value="" class="form-control" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-4 control-label">User Name</label>
<div class="col-lg-3"><input type="text" name="uname" value="" class="form-control" />
<span>Name is Same as Username</span>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Password</label>
<div class="col-lg-3"><input type="password" name="pwd" value="" class="form-control" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Email</label>
<div class="col-lg-3"><input type="email" name="email" value=""  class="form-control"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Mobile</label>
<div class="col-lg-3"><input type="number" name="mno" value="" class="form-control"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Works at</label>
<div class="col-lg-3"><input type="text" name="cmp" value="" class="form-control"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Designation</label>
<div class="col-lg-3"><input type="text" name="desg" value="" class="form-control"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
<div class="col-lg-3"> <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="welcome()"/>
<a href="index.jsp" class="btn btn-warning">Back</a>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</center>
<!-- end #footer -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting your form with register data to empadd.jsp as written here

```
<form action="empadd.jsp" class="form-horizontal">
```

And also you are showing an alert onclick, which is not correct structure wise.

If you need to do this using javascript, you can do this --

```
window.location.href = './login.jsp';
```

And If you want to do redirection in empadd.jsp, then you can do this --

```
response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
```

It's all your choice!